# c++ programs are not working properly

Tags: programming, c++

```
/* write a prog to take the name of the user and output it with a thank you stamement*/

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 char ch[20];
 cout<<"enter your name pls"<<endl;
  cin >> ch>>endl;
  cout<<"thank you::"<<ch<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
ff@ff-desktop:~/CCCP/ch1$ g++ 2.cpp -o 2
2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
2.cpp:9: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::operator>> [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)(& std::cin)), ((char&)(& ch))) >> std::endl’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:119: note: candidates are: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:123: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:130: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:166: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:170: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:173: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:177: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:180: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:184: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:188: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:193: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:197: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:202: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(float&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:206: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:210: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:214: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:238: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:741: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>&, _CharT2*) [with _CharT2 = char, _Traits2 = std::char_traits<char>, _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/istream.tcc:853: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
ff@ff-desktop:~/CCCP/ch1$
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

ACTIONPARSNIP(ANDREW-WOODHEAD666) suggested this:

> Try changing:   `#include <iostream>`
>
> To:   `#include "iostream"`
>
> Or try:   `#include <iostream.h>`
>
> or:   `#include "iostream.h"`

*And after doing these changes, I got the following.*

Here is the output for the same program above, with `"iostream.h"` instead of `<iostream.h>`:

```
2.cpp:2:21: error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
2.cpp:8: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
2.cpp:8: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
2.cpp:9: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone please help in this and suggest me whats wrong?

Comment: It is an error in your program ,but it is offtopic here , this may ontopic in stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm not sure this is off-topic, because compilers / STL implementations on some other platforms might actually accept an overload that allows calling `operator>>` with an `std::istream` on the left and an `std::ostream&` on the right. But I do strongly agree that this would be better on Stack Overflow, as it's not *fundamentally about* a platform-specific issue.

Answer (score 4):

`#include <iostream>` was correct. (Actually, you had `#include<iostream>`, without a space, but that is correct too.) Including `"iostream.h"` or `<iostream.h>` instead are actually both wrong, though some compilers and standard libraries will accept them.

This problem is because the standard library doesn't provide an overload of `operator>>` that can take an `std::istream` on the left and an `std::ostream&` on the right. To put it more plainly, this is where your error is happening:

```
cin >> ch>>endl;
```

- Please note that this is equivalent to `(cin >> ch) >> endl`, and it's the `>>` outside the parentheses where the error is happening, though changing the parentheses to try to pass `ch` and `endl` as arguments to `>>` would also be wrong.
- `endl` is an `ostream&` and `cin` is an `istream`. `>>` cannot operate with an `istream` on the left and an `ostream&` on the right, as the STL doesn't define any overload that can be selected for such an expression.

You can use `endl` with `cout`, but you cannot use it like this with `cin`.

How to fix this depends on what you *intended* to do.

- If your goal is to print a newline after taking input, add a separate statement (`cout << endl`) after this, or add `endl` to the subsequent statement with `cout` that you already have.
- If your goal is to stop taking input when a newline is encountered, that will *already* happen using `<<` with `cin`, so just remove the `endl` part altogether:

  ```
  cin >> ch;
  ```
- If your goal is to *keep* taking input when any whitespace *except* a newline is encountered (that is, you want to make sure to read exactly one line of input into a `char` array or`std::string`), you will have to use a more complex expression, or perhaps not even use `operator>>` with `cin` at all.

  Since it's not clear that is what you want, and solutions for doing that are not platform specific (whereas what overloads are available in an STL implementation is at least *theoretically* platform-specific), details about how to do that are beyond the scope of this answer. But if that's what you want to do, I recommend asking on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score -1):

You should use:`#include <iostream>` (don't forget about space) and `using namespace std;`

Compile it by following this syntax: `g++ -o 2 2.cpp`

If this doesn't work then: `find /usr/include -name iostream -type f -print` and add it to your include path

Comment: You don't need a space (though personally I think it looks better with one). The original error was not due to a wrong `#include` directive. `<iostream>` was being properly included. The modified source code *did* introduce a wrong `#include` directive, but just fixing that won't fix the original error (which is due to [an attempt to call an overload of `operator>>` that `<iostream>` does not provide](http://askubuntu.com/a/169101/22949)).